# HOw to enable shell login for particular user in one ip

Tags: shell, centos5

I have blocked FTP 21 port on server. NOw every connection will be via SFTP via ssh.

Initially i had `/etc/hosts.deny -- sshd:all`

But i had to remove that otherwise sftp was not working.

How can i secure my shell login so that if someone login via root or userbac(root previleges)

Then i need private key but not for other users

Or any other to secure my system

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do a couple of things:

1) Require an RSA key for login to ssh.

2) Block port 22 on iptables with a single exception for the IP that you want to allow.

Comment: if i block port 22 or use RSA key will my clients be able to use SFTP